# is google cloud metadata is zonal or global?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sdk

While working on zonal DR strategy , we came across few doubt if

gcloud instance describe  --zone=us-east4-a  work in zonal outage ? or it will fail. We are only fetching metadata of the VM which has zonal outage i.e entire zone (data center) is down

Comment: Please clarify your question. What do you mean by metadata? That word has many meanings and another in Google Cloud.

Comment: let me clarify , if I need to execute "gcloud compute  instance describe" command on impacted instance  during zonal outage , will i get output or due to zonal outage my command will not fetch details(metadata) about instance?

Comment: Do you mean if an entire zone (data center) is down or do you mean an instance is down in a particular region? Edit your question instead of using comments.

Comment: Updated question ,if an entire zone (data center) is down

Comment: If an entire zone is down, you will not be able to connect to the zone to fetch data about instances in that zone.